# How to refactor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dialog, refactoring

I'm biginner at flutter and I don't know how to refactor.

I don't want to write same Dart attribute in every class.

```
getAlert_1({required BuildContext context,required String title, required String msg}){
 return AwesomeDialog(
  context: context,
  title: title,
  desc: msg,
  dialogType: DialogType.INFO
  )..show();
}

getAlert_2({required BuildContext context,required String title, required String msg}){
 return AwesomeDialog(
  context: context,
  title: title,
  desc: msg
  dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES
  )..show();
}

getAlert_2({required BuildContext context,required String title, required String msg}){
 return AwesomeDialog(
  context: context,
  title: title,
  desc: msg,
  dialogType: DialogType.WARNING
  )..show();
}
```

I want to refactor below code.

```
  context: context,
  title: title,
  desc: msg,
```

Please teach me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file that will hold a class that will have a function that returns a customized widget and you can reuse throughout the project.

Create a file called customAwesomeDialog.dart.

In the file, create as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAwesomeDialog {

  CustomAwesomeDialog();


  generateDialog(BuildContext context, String title, String description) {
   return AwesomeDialog(
    context: context,
    title: title,
    desc: description
    dialogType: DialogType.SUCCES
   )..show();
  }
 }
```

Now go to any class file you want to call this widget.
Import the above class.

```
import ‘customAwesomeDialog.dart’;
```

Instantiate the class

```
 CustomAwesomeDialog cDialog = CustomAwesomeDialog();
```

Then use it within the class

```
cDialog.generateDialog(context, “Success”, “You have made it”);
```

Comment: I rewrite my code and show this in above answer.